# Minimally clued 5x5 Hidato

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>Puzzle attribution: Me</sub>

---

Goal of Hidato:

> Fill in a grid with a series of consecutive numbers that connect each other orthogonally or diagonally

To get the green checkmark $\color{green}✓$:

> - Solve the puzzle (showing solution process is optional) or show that no solution exists/the solution is not unique

The puzzle:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   |   |   | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |20 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|16 |   |   |   | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is

> not unique. In the grid below, the 15 and 25 can be entered in the empty spots in either order.
>
> ```
>  1  12 11 10 9
>  13 2  23 22 8
>  14 24 3  21 7
>  .  .  20 4  6
>  16 17 18 19 5
> ```

> You can also reverse 21-25 as follows (and then you can still swap 25 and 7):
>
> ```
>  1  12 11 10 9
>  13 2  23 24 8
>  14 22 3  25 7
>  15 21 20 4  6
>  16 17 18 19 5
> ```